# NSLayout Constraint Conflict in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I've added several layout constraints to the children of a UITableViewCell, all of which seem reasonable to me. However, the view throws a warning, telling me I have a conflict between the following layout constraints:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428f780 H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x17419d5a0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCell:0x14cd88d10 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428f7d0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x17419d5a0.trailing == UITableViewCell:0x14cd88d10.trailing>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428fbe0 H:|-(10)-[UILabel:0x14cd842b0'Name'](LTR)   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x17419d5a0 )>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428fcd0 UITextField:0x14cd82d10.right == UITableViewCellContentView:0x17419d5a0.right - 10>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428fdc0 H:[UILabel:0x14cd842b0'Name'(50)]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428feb0 H:[UILabel:0x14cd842b0'Name']-(10)-[UITextField:0x14cd82d10](LTR)>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170289a10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCell:0x14cd88d10(0)]>
```

As a consequence, it attempts to break the following constraint:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428feb0 H:[UILabel:0x14cd842b0'Name']-(10)-[UITextField:0x14cd82d10](LTR)>
```

Now first of all, the layout was set up programmatically and the label, the field, and the contentView have all had `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false. Second, none of the constraints seem to be in conflict on the surface, at least intuitively. Third, when I disable the constraint the error is reporting that it's breaking and rerun, the textfield, unsurprisingly, collapses to 0 width.

Is there something I'm missing or something going on behind the scenes that I'm not addressing?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: sure, but what exactly do you want a screenshot of?

Comment: Two; First of you cell in storyboard, second of your cell during execution when this warning is thrown.

Comment: Like I said in the post, it was done programmatically--there's no storyboard layout

Comment: @blacksquare I'm running into the exact same problem. Were you able to discover a solution?

Comment: You might want to throw some identifiers into debug your layout. Here's how to do it--> http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/08/17/using-identifiers-to-debug-autolayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds;
```

in :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to solve this question.